# What's the input shape for an SVM classifier?

Tags: svm

I have a dataset with tensors (there are 12 classes) of shape `(700,2000)` - height is 700 and width is 2000. I would like to try to use an SVM classifier (just to see how it does). My question is - how do I input the data? Do I flatten it? So the input arrays would be 1 dimensional with length `700*2000`?

Comment: Can you clarify if (700, 2000) is the shape of the dataset, or of a single example in the dataset? Also, it might help to know what kind of software you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the software is probably expecting an $N$ examples (or records) by $M$ (features) array as the input matrix $X$, plus a 1D array of length $N$ as the expected output labels (with 12 unique values, corresponding to the 12 classes).

So if you're saying that your entire dataset is 700 × 2000, just use it as-is.

On the other hand, if you're saying that one single example of your data is 700 × 2000, then you would need to flatten each example into a 1,400,000-feature vector... but this is a very high-dimensional vector, and although SVMs are good at high-dimensional data, it can lead to problems (see [the curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality)). So you could either reduce the size of the original examples, or take some steps to otherwise [reduce the dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) of your data.